# Firestarter preventing Firefox accessing internet

Tags: 12.04, firefox, firewall, firestarter

I have recently had an issue with Firestarter preventing Firefox accessing the Internet. I have used Firestarter in the past with Hardy Heron and recently switched to Precise Pangolin.

The policy settings I used with Hardy for Firestarter are:

```
outbound traffic policy
restrictive by default - whitelist traffic
HTTP 80 - everyone
HTTPS 443 - everyone
POP3 110 - everyone
SMTP 25 - everyone
```

these settings worked fine on Hardy and until this past Friday worked fine on Precise. Then I started to get the message `Server not found` when opening Firefox. The only way to access the Internet is to disable the firewall. In case it's a hardware issue, I am using a Zepto Znote 3215W laptop (wired Internet connection).

Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Any help greatly appreciated (I'm still learning about Linux).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow port `53` TCP & UDP for DNS and ports `67` & `68` UDP for DHCP.

Although I have never used Firestarter, because I prefer UFW.

Have a look at this [simple guide on my website for setting up UFW](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/firewall.html), it may help.